# Find the last two digits of the number $7^{100}-8^{100}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I tried and found that $$7^{100} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$$ but I got stuck with $8^{100}$. Help me out please.

Comment: hint -- see what can we doing with assistance http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+a%5E10-b%5E10

Comment: How are you getting stuck with $8$?

Comment: Actually I got $8^{20} \equiv 24 (mod 100)$, but I need something simpler then this.

Comment: Assuming what you said, $7^{100}-8^{100}\equiv 101-24\pmod{100}$?

Comment: Meaning of "last two digits" when the number is negative?

Comment: @GEdgar I have the same concern - se below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the binomial expansion

$$(2+5)^{100}=2^{100}+100\cdot2^{99}\cdot5+{100\choose2}2^{98}\cdot5^2+\cdots+{100\choose98}2^2\cdot5^{98}+100\cdot2\cdot5^{99}+5^{100}$$

It's easy to see that all the interior terms are divisible by $2^2\cdot5^2=100$, hence

$$7^{100}=(2+5)^{100}\equiv2^{100}+5^{100}\equiv2^{100}+25\mod100$$

It's even easier to see that expanding the binomial for $(2-10)^{100}$ gives

$$8^{100}=(2-10)^{100}\equiv2^{100}\mod100$$

Hence

$$7^{100}-8^{100}\equiv25\mod100$$

(Remark:  I tried $7=10-3$ first, before discovering that $2+5$ did the trick.)

Comment: $7^{100}-8^{100}=(7^{25}-8^{25])(7^{25}+8^{25})(7^{50}+8^{50})$. $7^{25}-8^{25} =1-1 mod(25)=0 mod(25)$, that is it is equal to $n*25$ for some n. The last 2 digits are therefore 00, 25, or 75.  $7^{100}-8^{100} = 1^{100}-2^{100} mod(3)$ or $1-(-1)^100=1-1=0 mod(3)$ which points to -75?

Comment: @MikaelJensen, sorry, I can't read your MathJax, but as near as I can tell it has no bearing on my answer.

Comment: One thing, my question includes the probable answers to be one of $01$, $00$, $02$ and $03$. Is it wrong?

Comment: @KprimeX, I would say so, especially since Quang Hoang and I get the same answer by separate methods.

Comment: OK one more, when I tried WEB 2.0 scientific calculator then it shows the last two digits to be $75$.

Comment: Yes I appreciate both the methods, they are elegant.

Comment: @KprimeX, since $7\lt8$, the computed number is negative.  It's possible your calculator is computing that number, *ignoring the minus sign*, and reporting the last two digits.  Note that $-75\equiv25$ mod $100$, so the last two digits of a negative number congruent to $25$ mod $100$ are $75$. (This is what GEdgar was asking about in a comment beneath the OP.)

Comment: Got it ..... :)

Comment: @Barry Cipra I am sorry for my poor Tex knowledge I was not allowed to change my comment after a few minutes. $7^1{00−8^{100=1^{100−(-1)^{100} mod(3)$ makes the answer -75 mod(100) but I realise this is the same as 25.

Comment: @Barry Cipra v2 I apologize once more for my lack of Tex skills. I meant to say that my mod(25) view gave three options for the 2 last numbers, i.e. the result mod(100): 00,25 or 75 (which should be 00, -25 and -75., since  8>7). My mod(3) view shows that the result must be  -75 mod(100) which I now realize equals 25. With these corrections I actually believe my answer was the fastest.

Comment: @MikaelJensen, nothing to apologize for.  I understand what you're saying now.  You should really post it as an answer, not a comment.  It's good to have lots of approaches.

Answer (score 5):

First, note that $7^2\equiv8^2\pmod{5}$. So $$7^{100}-8^{100}=(7^2-8^2)\left((7^2)^{49}+(7^2)^{48}(8^2)+\cdots+(8^2)^{49}\right)\equiv 0\pmod{25},$$
since the second term consists of $50$ summands of the same modulo $5$.

Second $7^{100}-8^{100}\equiv 7^{100}\pmod{4}\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Chinese remainder theorem then implies that the answer is $25$.

Answer (score 2):

Following David Cipras advice let me give this answer:
The conjugate rule applied twice gives us 
$7^{100}-8^{100}= (7^{25}-8^{25})(7^{25}+8^{25})(7^{50}+8^{50})$ 
The first factor is 1-1 mod (25) = 0 mod (25) so the last numbers are 00,-25 or -75 mod(100)

And considering mod 3 we have:

$7^{100}-8^{100} = 1^{100}-(-1){100}=1-1=0$ mod(3) so the only alternatives are 00 or -75 mod (100).

I now must also consider mod (2) (not mentioned in my comment) to get 
$7^{100}-8^{100}= 1-0 $ mod (2) which rules out the alternative 00 and gives us -75 mod (100) that is the last two numbers are "25".

PS I am still worried about the negative numbers as mentioned in my first comment. Actually wolfram alpha gives  -2037032741857976461510454343761609060834657536462737346010739515459049908071877069255337375

Perhaps there is some kind of convention about this?

Comment: actually wolfram alpha gives  -2037032741857976461510454343761609060834657536462737346010739515459049908071877069255337375